# Is it okay to put middleware inside .then block of mongoose.connect? (More in a body of the question)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a simple express app here, in order for mongoose.connection.getClient() to work I need to have an already established connection to the database. Is it okay to put app.use(session()), app.use(passport.initialize()); and app.use(passport.session()); inside .then block of mongoose.connect?

So basically I'm asking if this code structure is ok

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import routes from "./routes/index.js";
import "./config/passport.js";

//Configurations
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//Database setup
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
   .then(() => {
      console.log("Database connection has been established");

      //Auth middleware
      app.use(session({
         secret: "secret",
         resave: false,
         saveUninitialized: false,
         store: MongoStore.create({ client: mongoose.connection.getClient(), collectionName: "sessions" }),
         cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60
         }
      }))
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());

      //Server listening
      const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
      app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`App is listeting on PORT ${PORT}`); });

   })
   .catch((err) => { console.log(`Database connection error: ${err}`); })


//Router
app.use(routes);

//Error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
   res.json({error: "Error:("})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you move the error handling center outside of the .then() block, you ensure that it catches errors that occur during the database connection process and other errors that may occur during application execution